# yii multiple inner joins

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am trying to write a query in yii. I have the following which works

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition = "($column = :id)";
$criteria->params = array(":id" =>  $id );
$rows = Jobs::model()->with('pROJ')->findAll($criteria);
```

This returns the model of Jobs in array. I need to write the following query in yii to return a model

```
SELECT jobs.JOBNO, jobs.STATUS, projects.ORDERNO, jobs.PROJID, jobs.NAME, jobs.SEQ, jobs.PCENTDONE, jobs.EARNED, jobs.VALUE, jobs.DATEIN, jobs.DATEDONE, jobs.DATEDUE, jobs.SENTBACK, jobs.ORIGTAPES, jobs.COMMENTS, projects.CATEGORY, orders.BIDNO
FROM (jobs INNER JOIN projects ON jobs.PROJID = projects.PROJID) INNER JOIN orders ON projects.ORDERNO = orders.ORDERNO
where jobs.projid =     3002001
ORDER BY jobs.JOBNO, jobs.PROJID
```

I have tried the following but it does not work

```
$rows = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('jobs.*, projects.ORDERNO, projects.CATEGORY, orders.BIDNO')
            ->from('jobs, projects, orders')
            ->join('projects p','jobs.PROJID = p.PROJID')
            ->join('orders o', 'p.ORDERNO = o.ORDERNO')
            ->where('jobs.projid=:id', array(':id'=>$id))
            ->queryRow();
```

I get the following error

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'jobs.PROJID' in 'on clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `jobs`.*, `projects`.`ORDERNO`, `projects`.`CATEGORY`, `orders`.`BIDNO`
FROM `jobs`, `projects`, `orders`
JOIN `projects` `p` ON jobs.PROJID=p.PROJID
JOIN `orders` `o` ON p.ORDERNO=o.ORDERNO
WHERE jobs.projid=:id
```

I have updated to

```
$rows = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                ->select('jobs.*, projects.orderno, projects.category, orders.bidno')
                ->from('jobs')
                ->join('projects p','jobs.projid = p.projid')
                ->join('orders o', 'p.orderno = o.orderno')
                ->where('jobs.projid=:id', array(':id'=>$id))
                ->queryRow();
```

but i still get the error. All columns in mysql are CAPS

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'projects.orderno' in 'field list'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `jobs`.*, `projects`.`orderno`, `projects`.`category`, `orders`.`bidno`
FROM `jobs`
JOIN `projects` `p` ON jobs.projid = p.projid
JOIN `orders` `o` ON p.orderno = o.orderno
WHERE jobs.projid=:id
```

Comment: On certain operating systems, such as Linux, MySQL table/column names are case sensitive.

Comment: `SELECT ... projects.orderno ... JOIN projects p`. You aliased `projects` to `p`, so you can no longer use `projects`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @DCoder said: your select should now read `select('jobs.*, p.orderno, p.category, o.bidno')`. For consistency you should also alias `jobs` as follows

```
$rows = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('j.*, p.orderno, p.category, o.bidno')
            ->from('jobs j')
            ->join('projects p','j.projid = p.projid')
            ->join('orders o', 'p.orderno = o.orderno')
            ->where('j.projid=:id', array(':id'=>$id))
            ->order('j.jobno,j.projid')
            ->queryRow();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove **projects, orders** from `->from('jobs, projects, orders')` and may be you should lower the case of `jobs.PROJID` as your error message says that it couldn't find the column.