# YII CActiveRecord Join Operator

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii-cactiverecord

I'm now still learning YII on blog tutorial.

I try to join many tables using CAtiveRecord:

```
   $q= Questions::model()->searchText($text);

    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider($q,array(
      'criteria'=>array(
            'with'=>array(
                'Ans'=>array(
                    'scopes'=>array(
                        'searchAns'=>$text,
                    ),
                  )

                )
            ),
            'together' => true,
       ),
       'pagination' => array('pageSize' => 10,),
    ));
```

but my result  is something like this :

```
   SELECT * FROM `Q` `t` 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `A` `ans` ON (`ans`.`q_id`=`t`.`id`) AND (ans.text LIKE :ycp2)
      WHERE (t.question LIKE :ycp0)  
   LIMIT 10
```

I need  my MySQL query to be like:

```
Select * FROM 
   Table as A 
       left Join Table as B on A.id=B.id_parent 
   where A.status = 1 OR B.status=2
```

Later edit

1.My relations and scopes are defined

Answer (score 0):

You should define [relations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr) in your model, that way you could get data like this easily.
If realtions are not enough, you have to build your query either with [CDbCriteria](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria), or simply add conditions when selecting out of your model.
But in any case it would ber nicer to do this before you get into the DataProvider.

Or in the worst case, when you do not know what to do, you can use the command builder:

[yii multiple inner joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072672/yii-multiple-inner-joins)

Comment: thanks for the answer Asped but by relations and scopes are already defined and I don't know how to set OR condition between tables